# /tmp folders keep popping up on ubuntu desktop?

Tags: 12.04, tmp

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and `/tmp` folders will pop up on the desktop for an unknown reason.  They'll take over the screen if I leave them for long enough.  How can I troubleshoot  / stop this from happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean that new folders are created at `/home/user/Desktop/tmp`. Or do you mean that the create folder is `/home/user/Desktop//tmp`? Or do you mean that a window pops up to show the content of `/tmp`?

In any case, did you recently install an application after downloading it? Something like Dropbox, ... Not after searching in the package manager. These packages often run things on session start and can have unexpected behaviour.

Try disabling your suspects in `Startup Applications` (System > Preferences).

Comment: I mean that windows are popping up showing the contents.